# Add tenant specific roles in Azure AD multitenant app

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing multitenant app in ASP.NET Core using Azure AD as authentication. I want to allow access to my app only for specific tenants (due to this I added valid issuers list to my app authorization).

Problem is I want to specify custom roles for each tennant. Why? Base scenario looks like this.

I have customer organization (Tenant) A with 3 departments named AB, AC and AD.

Meanwhile I have customer organization (Tenant) B with 5 departments BA, BB, BC, BD, BE.

I want to be able to grant users permissions excatly for their departments. For example grant user from tenant A access only to department AB (or all of them) and in perfect scenario it will be done by admin of company A in their Azure AD.

I was thinking of App roles from Azure AD but it seemed to me a very undesirable to expose in manifest all departments of all my customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this official doc first:

[Add app roles to your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#app-roles-ui)

The permissions function of Azure AD is not yet specific to the departmental permissions of the tenant.

This official document tells me that when we are in App Registration, we can add an App Role to other tenants (Test), and then our application can be accessed by the Test tenant.

However, the specific permissions for each department under each tenant should be controlled at the code level.

Comment: Okay, so this means that I should have all the users in my database (I should have tool for migrating and synchronizing users with my customers tenants) and create separate functionality for managing the accesses for departments? Or is there more suitable way?

Comment: @rethon012 There should be no better way to manage your department permissions. We can imagine that not all apps have permission management, and some may just be a publicity homepage. If there are departments or institutions in the app, how does aad know? Therefore, this business authority function should be considered before the program business design.

Comment: @rethon012 What aad can do is to restrict which tenant members can access the webapp. The permissions in the webapp need to be designed and considered at the code level.